# Trajectory following of 3-wheel omnidirectional robot

Tags: kinematics, path-planning

I created a three-wheeled omnidirectional robot on omni-wheels, there is also a program in which I can plot a trajectory when plotting a trajectory, such data are obtained (X, Y, Tangent X, Tangent Y, Theta), but I do not understand what formulas should be used to transform these are given in speed for each wheel[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean when you say x tangent and y tangent? I thought at first maybe it was some way of stating the heading, but you've got theta listed, too. Do you have a diagram that shows what all these terms mean and your robot's physical arrangement?

Comment: unfortunately, I myself cannot understand what these angles are calculated on, but to build the trajectory I use PathWeaver, it is included in the wpilib library.

Comment: link to patweaver : https://mcm-frc-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/software/wpilib-tools/pathweaver/drawing-pathweaver-path.html